# Powershell: Displaying two different text message depending on result

Tags: powershell, math, get-wmiobject

```
Get-WmiObject -Class Win32_logicaldisk -Filter "DriveType = '3'" | 
Select-Object -Property DeviceID, DriveType, VolumeName, 
@{N='FreeSpaceGB';E={"{0:N2}" -f ($_.FreeSpace /1GB)}},
@{N="Capacity";E={"{0:N2}" -f ($_.Size/1GB)}},
@{N="PercentageFree";E={"{0:N0}" -f ($_.Freespace*100/$_.Size)}}
```

I have this and everything work perfectly but now i want to show a message saying, "warning low disk space" if the result of the 'PercentageFree' section is below 15%
Brand new to this and had a look around but i'm still not sure what sort of lingo i should be using to research these things.

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add another column to the end of the `Select-Object`

```
@{N="Status";E={if ($_.Freespace*100/$_.Size -lt 15) { "Low Space" } else { "OK" } }}
```

Comment: Hi @JACKA, it is Stack Overflow courtesy to hit the green checkmark on the left of this answer to mark this as accepted so this question doesn't show up again. If this solved your problem hit the green mark. If another problem stemmed from this, mark this as accepted but ask a different question as it would be a different problem.